# Error when installing gpclib

Tags: r, google-maps, heatmap

R version 3.2.1

I downloaded gpclib_1.5-5.tar.gz from http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gpclib/index.html and attempted to install the package with

`install.packages("D:/GIS/gpclib_1.5-5.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")`

I get the error

```
* installing *source* package 'gpclib' ...
** package 'gpclib' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

*** arch - i386
Warning: running command 'make -f "D:/R/R-3.2.1/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "D:/R/R-3.2.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="gpclib.dll" OBJECTS="Rgpc.o gpc.o"' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'gpclib'
* removing 'D:/R/R-3.2.1/library/gpclib'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"D:/R/R-3.2.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "D:\R\R-3.2.1\library" "D:/GIS/gpclib_1.5-5.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘D:/GIS/gpclib_1.5-5.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

How do I troubleshoot this?

#### Extra Information

I am ultimately trying to create heat maps, and am following this tutorial

http://spatialanalysis.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/james_cheshire_ggplot_intro_blog.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to install Rtools to install the R compiler libraries:

http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

Otherwise, R will have issues compiling from source code.